# failed to upload multiple files simultaneously into mysql database using jsp

Tags: java, jdbc

I am trying to insert multiple records in MySQL database but my code is inserting only one record into MySQL database even if I prepare multiple statements in a loop. Please help me where I am getting wrong. I searched for this answer from 2 weeks.

Here is my code.. UploadServletClass.java.

```
String firstName = request.getParameter("firstname");
String lastName = request.getParameter("lastname");
String fileName = "";
String path = folderName + File.separator + fileName;

con = DB.getConnection();

List < Part > fileParts = request.getParts().stream().filter(part - > "file".equals(part.getName())).collect(Collectors.toList());

for (Part filePart: fileParts) {
    fileName = Paths.get(filePart.getSubmittedFileName()).getFileName().toString();
    filePart.write(uploadPath + File.separator + fileName);
    InputStream ins = filePart.getInputStream();
    String sql = "insert into newfiles(firstname,lastname,filename,path) values(?,?,?,?)"; //inserting all values into database
    ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    Files.copy(ins, Paths.get(uploadPath + File.separator + fileName), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
}

ps.setString(1, firstName);
ps.setString(2, lastName);
ps.setString(3, fileName);
ps.setString(4, path);
int status = ps.executeUpdate();

if (status > 0) {
    System.out.println("File Uploaded Successfully");
    System.out.println("Uploaded Path:" + uploadPath);
}
```

Comment: someone please help...

Comment: This is not a JSP/Servlet file upload problem. It's working perfectly fine. Your problem is just in how you create and execute SQL statements. You create multiple statements, but you execute only the last one. I have reduced the noise from the code to make your problem better focused. You should do that yourself in your next questions.

Comment: @BalusC thank you for correcting me. but I don't understand where I am wrong in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code:

```
ps.setString(1, firstName);
ps.setString(2, lastName);
ps.setString(3, fileName);
ps.setString(4, path);
int status = ps.executeUpdate();

if (status > 0) {
    System.out.println("File Uploaded Successfully");
    System.out.println("Uploaded Path:" + uploadPath);
}
```

inside your for-loop.

Comment: Thanks man. Problem solved. I also moved my "insert" statement after List<Part> statement.  :)